# My USB mouse cursor won't move

Tags: windows-10, laptop, usb, mouse, wireless-mouse

So basically, I can right click, left click, and use the scroll in the middle of my USB mouse.

1. I tried getting new batteries, didn't work.
2. When I replaced it the little green light on the bottom of the mouse turned on, but 5 seconds later it turned off. (Even with the light turned on it won't move).
3. I tried to update the driver, that didn't work.
4. I tried to remove the USB from my laptop and shut down then turn the laptop back on.
5. I tried going into control panel > hardware and sound > devices and printers, right clicked on the mouse I use and pressing remove device. I unplugged the USB after I did that and plugged it back in, didn't work either.
6. Then I also tried checking the mouse for dust, blow on it, clean it, and then put the new battery back in. The same thing that I said in #2 happened.

So is the mouse just done for or is there a problem with it or my laptop? I got it last year and the incident happened last night, when I was playing a game called Minecraft and my mouse suddenly stopped working. I assumed it was just the battery but I don't even know anymore...

Comment: Have you tried the mouse with a different PC?

Comment: Have your tried a different mouse with your laptop?

Comment: If buttons work but the cursor doesn't move, it means that the optical (position) sensor went bad, the laser died, or sensor, and the USB part is likely OK, and driver or battery change won't help. Apparently you were playing games too much :=(

Answer (score 0):

From what you've tried, it sounds like @AliChen is right; the optical/tracking part of your mouse is likely bad.  If it's still under warranty, you may be able to get it replaced by the vendor or manufacturer.  Otherwise, it's probably more cost-effective to get a new mouse rather than try to repair this one.

A couple things to try first, though, to rule out other possible problems:

- Try that mouse on another computer
- Try another mouse on that computer

Comment: I got a new mouse, but yes that mouse was completely wrecked. The new one works thankfully.